# how to check if a host is in your known_host ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

I have the following command works in my script that adds the host to the known hosts in ssh.

```
VAR2=$(expect -c '
 spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '"$REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP"'
 expect "*?assword:*"
 send "'"$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD"'\r"
 expect { 
 "Permission denied, please try again." {
 exit '"$WRONG_PASSWORD"' 
 }
 }
 ')
```

Works fine, but I need to control before the command if the host is already in known_hosts and not execute command if it is already in known_hosts. How can i check if an host is in known_hosts?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try: `ssh-keygen -F <hostname>`

Will show the `known_hosts` line(s) if the hostname fingerprint is found and the command returns `0`, otherwise nothing is shown and the command returns `1`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything, or even print anything to the screen. Strange.

Comment: @VinceKronlein, That should happen when no match found for your hostname. Only full matches returned.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad. I wasn't using just the hostname ie: google.com, I was trying to look for a key for a git repo using the git host ie: git@google.com ... once I used just the hostname alone it worked great.

Comment: if you like I trying to find out if there exists the key of SSH server listening to non-standard port (other than 22), use the following command:  

`ssh-keygen -F "[gerrit.example.com]:29418"`

Answer (score 3):

According to ssh-keygen(1) man page

> -F hostname  Search for the specified hostname in a known_hosts file, listing  any occurrences found.  This option is useful to find hashed
>   host  names or addresses and may also be used in conjunction with the 
>   -H option to print found keys in a hashed format.