# Bash: SSH: Checking if an IP or host with non standard port is in known_hosts

Tags: bash, if-statement, networking, ssh, known-hosts

I'm trying to test if a SSH host has been connected to before in a bash script. It uses a non-standard port.

I'm using a test as suggested from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136998/how-to-check-if-a-host-is-in-your-known-host-ssh) question/answer, and I know for certain the SSH host in this test is in known_hosts, but the test does not seem to work as expected.

Is it not possible to test for IP addresses using `ssh-keygen -F`? Or is this an issue with using non-standard ports (as a check for `some.host.com:4567` doesn't work here either)...

```
#!/bin/bash

# test for IP address
if ssh-keygen -F '192.168.1.10:1234'; then
    echo "Yes, a known host."
fi

## Expected Output:
#
## Host 192.168.1.10 found: line 6
#|1|hashblahblahblah
#Yes, a known host.
#
## Actual Output:
#
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh-keygen` expects square-brackets around the host/IP.  Thus, replace:

```
ssh-keygen -F '192.168.1.10:1234'
```

with:

```
ssh-keygen -F '[192.168.1.10]:1234'
```

You can check this by looking at `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.  The first item, after "markers" if any, on each line is a comma-separated list of hosts (with ports if nonstandard).    `ssh-keygen -F` seems to expect the same format on the command-line as is used in the file.

Comment: Quick follow-up. I was not able to get this working with variables. For example, this code returns empty: `ssh-keygen -F '[${remoteHost}]:${remotePort}'` with `remoteHost="192.168.1.10"` and `remotePort="1234"`. Any ideas?

Comment: @nooblag Shell variables do _not_ expand inside single-quotes.  Use double-quotes: `ssh-keygen -F "[${remoteHost}]:${remotePort}"`

Comment: Ahhh, great! Thanks @John1024!